# Apache Bench - failed request

Tags: apache, centos, apachebench

I'm trying to test apache server from one VM on another.
Running command:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 -s 30 http://192.168.2.156:80/
```

and I get circa 900 failed requests
On server I have wordpress filled with content generated by "FakerPress" addon

When I'm tesing external servers (form hosting company) I have 0 failed requests.

- Apache on my server has default configuration.
- Server OS: CentOS7
- Wordpress: 4.9.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with router between two computers and also VM's. When I connect computers directly with eachother and run apacheBench from native system everything works fine.